# Hide div if no table rows are visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few divs on a page each containing one table.
A user interacts with the table and hides some rows.
I want to hide the containing div if all the table rows in the containing table are hidden.
How can I do this in jQuery?

```
.div.mytable
 table
   tr
.div.mytable
 table
   tr
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Where's the code you tried?

Comment: posting the javascript I have is of no help as it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UVFP5/)

This hides the row you want to hide and hides it's parent div if all rows are hidden.

**JS**

```
$('.hide').click(function(){ 

    // This hides the nearest <tr>
    $(this).closest('tr').hide();

    // Number of <tr> of it's <table>
    var tableTrNumber = $(this).closest('table').find('tr').length;

    // Number of <tr> already hidden of it's <table>
    var tableTrHiddenNumber = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:hidden').length;

    // If my tr number are equal to the number of hidden tr then hide the div
    if(tableTrNumber == tableTrHiddenNumber)
    {
        $(this).closest('.mytable').hide();
    }
});
```

Every style and HTML structure is just to show you how it works. Feel free to adapt it to your needs. Of course you've to respect the hierarchy of elements.

If you don't like the `hide()` function you can put whatever effect you want like a fade or accordion.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

You can target the containing div or put a class on each of the containing divs

```
<div class="containerDiv">
   <table>
  </table>
   </div>
```

Use the simple jQuery .has() method

```
 if($(".containerDiv table").has("tr")){
  $(this).parent(".containerDiv").hide();
 }
```

Wrap it in a function and call the function when ever the interaction happens.

Comment: the rows aren't removed just hidden

Comment: what do mean by hidden. Are they display:none? visibility:hidden?

Comment: using jquerys' .hide()